# H2 database automatically trying to create itself in Slick

Tags: scala, h2, slick

So I have some code that looks like this:

```
val conn_str = "jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=MYSQL;INIT=runscript from 'schema.sql'"
val database = Database.forURL(conn_str, driver="org.h2.Driver"
database withTransaction {
   // add some stuff to the database
   // query database
}
```

When it gets to the withTransaction block, an exception is thrown:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table already exists; SQL statement: ...
```

and the stack trace looks like it is trying to create the table using the ddl syntax for Slick. At no point did I ever specify that I want to the database to created using Slick. Is this an H2 thing, because I have run similar code using the MySQL driver and an actual database without problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so my problem was misunderstanding how INIT works in H2. It performs the action (in this case, runscript from ...) every time a connection is made to the database. I thought that it should only get executed when the database was created. In my .sql file, I had `CREATE TABLE` statements, so they got executed every time a connection was made. They should have been `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`. Add the `IF NOT EXISTS` solved my problem.

[Here](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#execute_sql_on_connection) is the relevant piece of documentation describing this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Also, when you have multiple test classes for the same slick database connection, and in each test if you recreated the table each time, make sure to disable parallel execution for test.

Answer (score -1):

This exception is idiomatic to H2 and can be ignored (see official documentation).

Comment: Is [this](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#creating_new_databases) the piece of documentation you are referring to? I can't seem to find anything else applicable.

Comment: Also, how would the exception be ignored? If the exception occurs when creating a transaction, how would I actually run any queries or insertions?

Comment: I have no clue what you mean with "This exception is idiomatic to H2". I first had to check what idiomatic means, but this word doesn't seem to make sense in this context.